# Django rest framework: Nested object not passing to validated_data

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

This is surely a problem in my understanding of how the serializer should work.

After changing a property permissions on my serializer, I found out that my Author nested object is turning out empty on the validated_data.

Here's my code :

```
class ThreadSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    class Meta:
            model = Thread
            queryset=Thread.objects.all()
            fields = ('id', 'title', 'description', 'author', 'created_at')

    pk = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    title = serializers.CharField(required=False, allow_blank=False, max_length=100)
    description = serializers.CharField(style={'base_template': 'textarea.html'}, required=False)
    author = AuthorSerializer()
    created_at = serializers.DateTimeField(required=False)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        """
        Create and return a new `Thread` instance, given the validated data.
        """
        author_data = validated_data.pop('author')
        if author_data:
            author = Author.objects.get_or_create(**author_data)
            validated_data['author'] = author

        return Thread.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

The payload is also quite simple:
`{ "title": "2", "description": "testing nested objects", "author": { "name": "ron", "email" : "email@mail.com" }}`

Yet, on the validated_data variable all I see is an empty OrderedDict.

Can someone point me to where I should be fixing this?

Comment: so you are absolutely sure that `validated_data` is empty? also noticed that you are subclassing from regular `Serializer`, not `ModelSerializer` which is required to use Django models

Comment: After testing the client side of the app I found out it was actually a problem of the json data being passed to DRF as a form and not as contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8". @miki725 I also did not realise the ModelSerializer needed to be used. Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here was on the client-side.

Information was being passed as form-data and not as application/json on the ajax request.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out this thing. I had the same problems and was devastatingly looking for the answer for a week.